# docker login - where are login credentials saved on the server?

Tags: docker

I am using some **service account** for `docker login` operation to our company repo.
Password expires and needs to be changed after 1 year period.
Once I start VM where docker is installed, my **service account** credentials are immediately locked, and I am not able to update new password with `docker login` since account is locked. It seems like it references and consumes somewhere old password, I do not run any docker operation automatically on the server side.

Where does server/VM stores information about old password - so I could remove/update those old data?

What I could try/check?

Thank you

Comment: How you store and use your credentials is specific to whatever code and scripts you are running. A script somewhere is running `docker login`, but we certainly can't tell you where that script is. But maybe this might help https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Comment: I can see that it saves the information in: `\.docker\config.json.` Should I remove this file or what should be the steps? `WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\me\.docker\config.json.`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid can nginx ngress controller deployment trigger `docker login` command? That is the only deployment which I have active

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid also I had a service active for my deployment which was using the secret with old password. But, I have deleted deployment long time ago, while service is still present. Can that cause the issue? active service or active nginx ingress controller deployment (serves as a load balancer)? Thanks

Comment: You're asking about ingress controllers and deployments, but asking about help with Docker. Those are Kubernetes terms. Asking us where to look in a complex project without details of how we could reproduce your issue doesn't make a good question for SE.

Comment: `docker login` is docker related topic

Comment: Is it possible to somehow do the search through the server and find what can trigger `docker login` command?

Comment: Something somewhere is calling `docker login`. Since it appears to be related to VM startup, the two places I would check are firstly task scheduler https://www.wintips.org/how-to-start-a-program-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/ and secondly go through services and see if any auto startup services are doing this. I suggest you also do a VM wide text search on `docker login` to see if you can find a script that's doing this. I assume there is no doco or handover on how this was set up originally.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you I found some login in Services for the service account user.  So that was causing an issue. So its resolved now :) thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post back a detailed answer and describe these services? This may help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: I did provide an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by disabling the Windows Service which referenced service account credentials for starting the service. This caused user locking.
It was Azure Pipeline Agent service which had as a logon account service account  old credentials.

The error, and traces can be noticed in the **Event Viewer** - it reported errors such as:
`The Azure Pipelines Agent ("service_name") service failed to start due to the following error:  The service did not start due to a logon failure.`

and

`The vstsagent."service_name" service was unable to log on as Domain\svcacct-user with the currently configured password due to the following error:  The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.`